# Using results from Nmaximize in loop

Tags: mathematical-optimization, assignment

I try to `Append` the vector `S` by `z+x` whereby `z` and `x` are calculated before. I somehow fail to extract `x` and `z` in the right way from the maximization problem. For some reason the standard solutions I found in the internet didn't work ( I probably failed to apply them correctly...)

```
S = {};
For[n = 3, n <= 10, n += 1,
 y =    NMaximize[{z,  n* x*z <= 1, x > 1/2} ,   {x, z}]    ;
 AppendTo[S, [z + x], n] ;]
```

It would be great, if you could write the correct syntax into the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should favour `Reap`+`Sow` instead of `AppendTo`.
2. You have a syntax error `[z + x]` with unnecessary brackets.
3. The `z` and `x` are not assigned any values but you are using them. You need to extract the values for `z` and `x` from the `NMaximize` results first.

```
S = Reap[
   For[n = 3, n <= 10, n += 1,
    {xresult, zresult} = 
     Values[Last[NMaximize[{z, n*x*z <= 1, x > 1/2}, {x, z}]]];
    Sow[xresult + zresult];
    ]][[2, 1]]

(** results: {1.16667, 1., 0.9, 0.833333, 0.785714, 0.75, 0.722222, 0.7} **)
```

You could also do away with the `For` loop entirely:

```
S = Total[Values[Last[NMaximize[{z, #*x*z <= 1, x > 1/2}, {x, z}]]]] & /@ Range[3, 10]
```