# Avoid "Initial points not satisfying constraint"

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have this maximization problem which works for many examples I run before I made the `For` loops.

```
def[s_, cs_] := cs s
main[S_, cm_] := cm S
y[S_, Tp_, tech_] := Sqrt[S (Tp + tech)]

        
delta = 1; M = 2; V = 2; dec = 1; db = 10^3; ts = 0; 
fs = 0; h = 0; re = 40^2; l = 0; p = 1; pm = 1; S = 1;
cb = 1; eps = 1; epsm = 1; tech = 1; 
        
For[K = 1, K < 100, K += 50,
  For[cs = 1, cs < 100, cs += 50,
    For[cm = 1, cm < 100, cm += 50,
      {tc1, s1, C11, b1} = 
        Values[Last[
          NMaximize[
            C1 - b db + h - cm (s + S) - re tc - cb (M + V) + epsm pm Sqrt[(s + dec S) (M + tech+V)],
            Reduce[
              {0 <= tc, tc <= M, C1 >= 0, s >= 0, b >= 0, K + eps p y[S, V + delta tc, tech] - def[s, cs] - main[S, cm] - C1 + b >= 0, C1 >= cb (M + V)},
              {tc, s, C1, b}, Reals
            ],
            {tc, s, C1, b}
          ]
        ]](*Values, Last*)
    ](*For*)
  ](*For*)
](*For*)
```

From my understanding satisfying

```
K + eps p y[S, V + delta tc, tech] - def[s, cs] - main[S, cm] - C1 + b >= 0
```

should not be a problem, because I allow `b` to be very high. So I really do not understand what the error message about "Initial Interval" is all about.

How do I have to change my code?

Comment: Often a non-issue but can be: `? K` reveals that `K` is a symbol used internally by *Mathematica*.

Comment: At a minimum something is wrong with your syntax in `NMaximize`. Did you mean to include the equation and the Reduce expression in `{ }`? Otherwise it just won't work at all. Furthermore, `For` returns Null, so you are continuously writing over the previous iteration's result and will only get the very last value. [It has already been recommended to you](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230980/27951) to include `Reap` and `Sow`. Generally speaking, avoid loops unless you really really have to; you might use `Table` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives an answer:

```
Block[{k = 51, cs = 51, cm = 51},
 NMaximize[{C1 - b db + h - cm (s + S) - re tc - cb (M + V) + 
    epsm pm Sqrt[(s + dec S) (M + tech + V)], 
   Simplify[
    And @@ {0 <= tc, tc <= M, C1 >= 0, s >= 0, b >= 0, 
      k + eps p y[S, V + delta tc, tech] - def[s, cs] - main[S, cm] - 
        C1 + b >= 0, C1 >= cb (M + V),
      (s + dec S) (M + tech + V) >= 0, y[S, V + delta tc, tech]^2 >= 0}
    ]},
  {tc, s, C1, b},
  Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "InitialPoints" -> (
      {tc, s, C1, b} /. FindInstance[{
         k + eps p y[S, V + delta tc, tech] - def[s, cs] - 
           main[S, cm] - C1 + b >= 0,
         (s + dec S) (M + tech + V) >= 0, 
         y[S, V + delta tc, tech]^2 >= 0},
        {tc, s, C1, b},
        20
        ])
    },
  MaxIterations -> 500
  ]
 ]

(*  {-2316.71, {tc -> 0., s -> 0., C1 -> 4., b -> 2.26795}}  *)
```

I had to add some missing `{}` and some constraints to keep the `Sqrt` terms real.  The principal fix is to use `FindInstance` to find initial points.

Comment: If you have an idea about bounds on the variables, you can use `RandomPoint` + `ImplicitRegion`, which seems a little faster: `Block[{k = 51, cs = 51, cm = 51},
 RandomPoint[
  ImplicitRegion[
   And @@ {k + eps p y[S, V + delta tc, tech] - def[s, cs] - main[S, cm] - C1 + b >= 0, (s + dec S) (M + tech + V) >= 0, y[S, V + delta tc, tech]^2 >= 0}, {tc, s, C1, b}],
  20,   {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}]
 ]`

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked out perfectly